# Doubleton class - transition from single to double

Tags: c++

Below I managed to create a singleton class that allows the instantiation of an object.

How can I modify the code as simple as possible to get a "Doubleton", to have two objects?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


class Singleton
{
public:
    static Singleton& instance()
    {
        return uniqueInstance;
    }
    int getValue() { return data;}
    void setValue(int value) {  data = value;}

private:
    static Singleton uniqueInstance;
    int data;
    Singleton(int d = 0):data(d)     {    }
    Singleton & operator=(Singleton & ob){
       if (this != &ob) data = ob.data; return *this; }
    Singleton(const Singleton & ob) { data = ob.data; }
};
Singleton Singleton::uniqueInstance (0);



int main()
{
    Singleton& s1 = Singleton::instance();
    cout << s1.getValue() << endl;
    Singleton& s2 = Singleton::instance();
    s2.setValue(9);
    cout << s1.getValue() <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have an `instance2()`?

Comment: but why? the hole purpose of singelton is to have one instense?

Comment: your idea is not so cool.... even asuming that you defined 2 internal instances... which of them sould the ::getInstance() returns??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Templetize" it:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template<int N>
class Singleton {
 public:
  static Singleton& instance() {
    return uniqueInstance;
  }
  int getValue() const { return data; }
  void setValue(int value) { data = value; }

 private:
  static Singleton uniqueInstance;
  int data;
  Singleton(int d = 0) : data(d) {}
  Singleton& operator=(Singleton& ob) {
    if (this != &ob) data = ob.data;
    return *this;
  }
  Singleton(const Singleton& ob) { data = ob.data; }
};

template<int N>
Singleton<N> Singleton<N>::uniqueInstance(0);

int main() {
  Singleton<0>& s1 = Singleton<0>::instance();
  cout << s1.getValue() << endl;
  Singleton<1>& s2 = Singleton<1>::instance();
  s2.setValue(9);
  cout << s2.getValue() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

But to be honest, this is an anti-pattern if you need to do this I'd suggest reviewing the architecture...